# pause Loop within the listener until the key is pressed

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

I am trying to make an auto script to do some actions till a key "e" is pressed . It shows me a weird error although I imported all the required libraries .

```
import easygui
import keyboard
import pynput
from pynput import *
import pyautogui
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

def start_auto_click(k):
      while True:
                if pynput.keyboard.is_pressed('e'):
                    print('You Pressed e Key!')
                    break  # finishing the loop

def on_release(key):
   if keyboard.Key.space:
        b_ignore_mouse_events = True
        start_auto_click(key)
   elif key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        m_listener.stop()
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as k_listener, \
        mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as m_listener:
    k_listener.join()
    m_listener.join()
```

**the Error**

```
  File "/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/Auto/t.py", line 41, in start_auto_click
    if pynput.keyboard.is_pressed('e'):
AttributeError: module 'pynput.keyboard' has no attribute 'is_pressed'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your imports are a little messy, I'd recommend avoiding `import *` or `from x import *` as it makes it more difficult to track down which libraries/functions you're invoking.

You already have an event handler for key release events, so it would be easiest to add another `elif` statement to handle releasing <kbd>E</kbd>.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import time
from random import randint as randy
from pynput import keyboard

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char("e"):
        global stop
        stop = True
        return False  # stop the listener
    
# create a non-blocking listener
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

stop = False
while not stop:
    print(f"Rolling 2d6: {randy(1,6) + randy(1,6):2}")
    time.sleep(0.2)
print("Finished!")
```

This will print out something like:

```
Rolling 2d6:  2
Rolling 2d6: 11
Rolling 2d6: 11
Rolling 2d6:  6
Rolling 2d6:  6
Rolling 2d6:  9
Rolling 2d6:  8
Rolling 2d6:  7
Rolling 2d6:  9
Rolling 2d6:  9
Rolling 2d6:  7
Rolling 2d6:  6
Rolling 2d6: 11
Rolling 2d6:  8
Finished!
>>> e
```